# Pascal record with string

Tags: pascal

I'm trying to work with a record to store people names and phones.

It is my first time trying this in pascal but I'm stuck in a condition which never come true cause I don't know how to implement this IF yet.

If I try outside the IF it works, but it never will enter my condition.

tHIS CONDITION IS IN **procedure incluir_pessoa**.

**Main program**

```
program agenda1;

uses agenda1_procedures;

begin
  processar_agenda;
end.
```

**Procedures**

```
unit agenda1_procedures;

interface

uses crt, ReadAnyKey1;

type type_sexo = (feminino, masculino, outro);
type Type_pessoa = record
     primeiro_nome, ultimo_nome: string;
     sexo: type_sexo;
     telefone: string;
     end;
type type_pessoas = array of type_pessoa;

var pessoa: type_pessoas;

procedure processar_agenda;
procedure imprimir_menu(var escolha: char);
procedure processar_escolha(var escolha: char);
procedure incluir_pessoa(var pessoa: type_pessoas);

implementation

//---------------------------------------
// PROCESSAR AGENDA
//---------------------------------------
procedure processar_agenda;
var escolha: char;
begin

  repeat
    imprimir_menu(escolha);
    processar_escolha(escolha);
  until escolha = '0';

end;

//---------------------------------------
// IMPRIMIR MENU
//---------------------------------------
procedure imprimir_menu(var escolha: char);

begin


  clrscr;
  writeln('****************************************************************************************');
  writeln('* MENU                                                                                 *');
  writeln('****************************************************************************************');
  writeln('* 0-Sair                                                                               *');
  writeln('* 1-Incluir pessoa                                                                     *');
  writeln('* 2-Modificar pessoa                                                                   *');
  writeln('* 3-Excluir pessoa                                                                     *');
  writeln('*                                                                                      *');
  writeln('*                                                                                      *');
  writeln('****************************************************************************************');
  gotoxy(3,9); write('Digite uma escolha: '); read(escolha);

end;

//---------------------------------------
// INCLUIR PESSOA
//---------------------------------------
procedure incluir_pessoa(var pessoa: type_pessoas);
var i: integer;

begin

  if length(pessoa) = 0 then
    setlength(pessoa,1);

  writeln('Incluir pessoa na agenda');
  writeln;
readln;
  for i:=0 to length(pessoa) do
  begin
    readln;

//***** CONDITION WHICH NEVER COME TRUE !!!!! <------------------- *****

    if pessoa[0].primeiro_nome = ' ' then
    begin
      write('Primeiro nome: '); readln(pessoa[0].primeiro_nome);

//test
      writeln(pessoa[0].primeiro_nome); 
      readln;

    end;
  end;

//test
  write('Primeiro nome: '); readln(pessoa[0].primeiro_nome); 
  write('Pessoa:',pessoa[0].primeiro_nome);
  readln;
end;

//---------------------------------------
// PROCESSAR escolha
//---------------------------------------
procedure processar_escolha(var escolha: char);
begin
  case escolha of
  '0': exit;
  '1': incluir_pessoa(pessoa);
//  2:
//  3:
  end;
end;


end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to check if the name is empty? Or if it is a space character? Because in your condition you ask for a space.

Comment: Thank you my guy. My mistake.

I put a space in my condition but pascal needs no space im my IF as bellow.

Wrong: if pessoa[0].primeiro_nome = ' ' then |

Correct: if pessoa[0].primeiro_nome = '' then